# Roguelike development - jlabel over jlabel

Tags: java, layout, jlayeredpane

it's me again.
I'm still developping my roguelike, but I have another problem. I use a 2D array of Jlabel to display my map on a GridLayout, which is working perfectly fine. But now, I want to draw my character, monsters, etc. over the floor. Am I forced to switch my layout to a JLayeredPane, or is there any way I can achieve this whith my GridLayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use multiple `JPanel`s.

- If you are already done with map (floor), shift that code onto a `JPanel` (with `GridLayout`)
- Make another `JPanel` for displaying monsters and stuff. (With whichever `LayoutManager` you like).
- Add these `JPanel`s to your frame which has `JLayeredPane`.

So you'd have advantages of both.

**Note:** Don't forget to call `setOpaque(false)` on the `JPanel` on top.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought I would be able to do something faster to implements, but I guess I have no choice (it doesn't seems difficult though).

Answer (score 1):

Using JLabel is extremely slow, you should either use a monospace font and write directly to the graphics object of your JPanel or use a library.

- [SquidLib](https://github.com/SquidPony/SquidLib)
- libjcsi
- [Blacken](https://sites.google.com/site/blackenlib/)

I recommend mine, which is SquidLib. It is the most up to date, has the most features, and is the only one still in continued development. It is also the only one with a lot of examples and support for literally any font Java can load.

Blacken is good if you're more use to the curses or libtcod way of interfacing with a console, but they don't allow arbitrary font use.

No link to libjcsi because I don't have enough rep to post more than 2 links. It's easy enough to google though.